# Spring 5 MVC Angular 5 App Throwing 404 Error

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

I know this question has been asked before and I have tried several solutions but can't get this working properly. I'm using Spring 5 MVC and an angular app that exists in /src/main/webapp/.

The app works when accessing the base path. The problem comes when I need to jump into a route within the app. When the page tries to load with a route in the URL it's throwing a 404 error because Spring can't find a resource handler for that, but really what I want it to do is just go to the index.html of the app so angular can handle it. I've attempted to move the app inside an 'app' folder in /src/main/webapp/ and you can see the resource handlers and view controllers I have below. I use swagger for this app also which sort of complicates things. Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {...

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");   
    registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**").addResourceLocations("/app/");
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "swagger-ui.html");
    registry.addViewController("/swagger").setViewName("redirect:/rest/swagger-ui.html");
    registry.addViewController("/app").setViewName("forward:/app/index.html");
}
```

And the web initialization class below:

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
    // Create the 'root' Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(ApplicationConfiguration.class);

    // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    registerDispatcherServlet(container, MvcConfiguration.class, "/views/*", "/rest/*", "/swagger/*");

    container.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain")).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

    CharacterEncodingFilter charEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    charEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    container.addFilter("encoding-filter", charEncodingFilter).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

    container.addFilter("cors-filter", new CorsFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the base href property.

```
<base href="/src/main/webapp/">
```